# Unable to mock external api using Nock

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I have a Node.js service which calls an external API to gather some data before returning a response to the user. I want to mock this external API so I can test my service, but unfortunately the response I get back has no content (only a status of 200). Here is my test:

```
const nock = require('nock');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const request = require('supertest');
const httpStatus = require('http-status');

var app = require('../index');

describe('Get Account Summary test', function () {

    it('Should return a clients account summary successfully', function (done) {

        nock('https://external.api')
            .post('/v3/restful-api-endpoint')
            .reply(200, {
                "status": 200,
                "message": "This is a mocked response"
            });

        request(app)
            .get('/api/account/summary/dummy-request-id')
            .expect(httpStatus.OK)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                expect(res.body.message).to.equal('This is a mocked response');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

`res.body` returns undefined. I don't get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the source of your endpoint, it's difficult to say, but the problem is likely to lie there. There doesn't appear to be much wrong with the test itself. Be sure that you wait for your response from the external API (using promises, `async`/`await`, or a callback since that's often a source of confusion.

Comment: so my service uses the GET verb but I need to call the the external API using POST. That's why I have the POST on the external API call.

Comment: My bad, I missed that the routes were different. In that case, the response could be anything since we don't know what's in your endpoint's code. You may want to post that too.

Comment: Right...that makes sense actually. Because I'm taking one response and transforming it into another response. I need to figure out the transformation there

Comment: Yep! I'll amend my answer, and I guess post up if you still can't get it to work. Pro tip: make sure you're waiting for the response from the external API before responding, that's a common cause of undefined values.

Comment: You helped with tracking down the issue. Appreciate that.